# getting AssetManager to work in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to get [AssetManager](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager) to work in a plain new ZendSkeleton Application using [this Blog](http://ocramius.github.io/blog/asset-manager-for-zend-framework-2/) and the [wiki](https://github.com/RWOverdijk/AssetManager/wiki/Quick-start). I followed each step but can't get it to work, respectively tried every thing I could imagine... 
I'm using latest Zend2 Framework 2.2.6 and AssetManager dev-master via composer.
My files are located in ./module/Application/public. The Module is registered in ./config/application.config.php an loaded (testet via ZendDeveloperTools).

My config file ./module/Application/config/module.config.php is shown here:

```
return array(
   'asset_manager' => array(
        'resolver_configs' => array(
            'paths' => array(
                'Application' => __DIR__ . '/../public',
            ),
        ),
    ),
...
```

I have tried using maps and collections, but there is no way to access my files in "./module/Application/public" folder via "`http://localhost:8888/test.css`".

Anyone any idea how this problem could be solved?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Got any output for that HTTP request? What are the absolute paths of the module class, the `test.css` file and that config file?

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer :) I get an 404 error if I try to access this file via `http://localhost:8888/test.css` . The test.css is located here: `./module/Application/public/test.css`, the config file is  `./module/Application/config/module.config.php` and the module class is `./module/Application/module.php`. But the module class file isn't changed.

Comment: Is AssetManager enabled? Is your module enabled? Check the merged config and be sure to use `realpath()` to avoid problems with typos.

Comment: Yes AssetManager is enabled and the first module, checked via ZendDeveloperTools. I have edited `./module/Application/config/module.config.php` to `'Application' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../public'),` and it resolves correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I now that post is old, but anyway maybe it helps someone, i got same problem, issue was in my apache server configuration. In my `/etc/sites-available/*.conf` file I changed `AllowOverride None` to `All` and everything works now. My example of conf:

```
 <VirtualHost zend.loc:80>
        ServerName zend.loc
        DocumentRoot /var/www/zend.loc/public
        <Directory /var/www/zend.loc/public>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```